# XPages Social Business Toolkit

Tags: oauth-2.0, xpages, xpages-extlib, ibm-sbt

I am trying to implement XPagesSBT on localhost.
I have followed this article  http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/12152011034545AMNHECAP.htm and the SBT document by Niklas and was trying to implement dropbox oAuth.

I have also placed `http://localhost/XPagesSBT.nsf/ and http://localhost/WebSecurityStore.nsf` in root folder

but still i get this error

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=26: Error calling method 'isAuthenticated()' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sbt.services.client.endpoints.DropboxEndpoint'
No application is registered with id XPagesSBT and provider Dropbox



 if(!@Endpoint("dropbox").isAuthenticated()) {@Endpoint("dropbox").authenticate(true);}
```

do i need to make any other configuration /setup to XPagesSBT db? or it wont work with Localhost?

Comment: You can try to debug isAuthenticated method. Or look into sources for branch leading to your specific error. Definitely a misconfiguration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly anymore but reading my blog entry you linked it says you shouldn't use Anonymous:

"Additionally there are a couple of security related settings which are important to understand. First of all you need to assign access to the document with the application keys to the ID with which you signed the two NSFs. In the screenshot above I've entered both OpenNTF servers and my own user ID. When you use the web UI to do this these names are added to the document in an authors field and a readers field.

In the last step you need to configure the ACL of the security store. Anonymous must not have access to this database. All users who you want to be able to use the Social Enabler OAuth functionality need to have author access. This is so that their user keys can be stored in this database so that they only have to do the OAuth dance once. "

Comment: it works well when i put the nsf on a server and login with a notes id and configured my oAuths... Thanks for that suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work on localhost. It looks like a configuration issue with SBT not being able to read the security tokens from the websecuritystore.nsf . Did you create the Dropbox Application Key with an admin id and sign the websecuritystore with the correct id?

Padraic

Comment: i have added the oAuth Token for Dropbox in WebSecurityStore.nsf with Anonymous since its on localhost.